# how can I add dylib and static library in podspec file

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, podspec

For example, I have project A, and it need project B, so I use pod "Project B". But project B need some dylib and static library. So, I write project B podspec such as:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s| 
  s.name     = 'ProjectB'
  s.version  = '3.0.0'
  s.license  = 'MIT'
  s.summary  = 'ProjectB'
  s.homepage = 'urlAddress'
  s.authors  = { 'Jumei' => 'app@jumei.com' }
  s.source   = { :git => 'gitAddress', :branch => 'develop'}
  s.vendored_library = 'ProjectB_Dir/libmp3lame.a'
  s.library  = 'libc++.dylib'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.ios.deployment_target = '5.0'
 end
```

but thers is not libc++.dylib in project B.

Answer (score 10):

Please run `pod spec lint` on specs as you write them. We've removed the need for you to include `lib` and `.dylib` from included libraries. So in this case you should just use:

```
s.library = 'c++'
```

Comment: how can I add static library?